# Should I report a bad "First Post" audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I'm fairly new to the review queues and just got hit with my first audit warning.

Is it helpful/appropriate to report bad audits here, or is there some other action that should be taken?

General description of the case in question - I tried to comment asking for improvement. The question already has upvotes (so it's "good"), but existing comments (that were hidden) ask for the same improvements.

Comment: If it didn't get you banned there is not much to do. Visit the post yourself, cast a down vote if that is warranted. That should put the post out of the pool for audits.

Comment: If you disagree with the audit, you could still visit the post and do the action that made you fail the audit.

Comment: you should report bad audits here, so that no other have to suffer from it. (they suffer enough)

Comment: Yes, please; do report incorrect audits. Use the [[meta-tag:disputed-review-audits]] tag. Also do as Braiam suggested and visit the post to perform the action you wanted to perform within review. The act of downvoting and/or flagging a post instantly ensures it will not be selected as an audit anymore, and you can do either or both of those things yourself. In [this particular case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61559359/could-not-build-wheels-for-pyaudio-since-package-wheel-is-not-installed), you are more than correct. That's a terrible audit. I've handled it now.

Comment: @CodyGray The odd thing is that [someone actually did downvote that post 5 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61559359/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries#voteaggregate_637246655999999999). Why was this still an audit?

Comment: I don't know, @Ivar. Sounds like a [[meta-tag:bug]].

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for helping handle that! Seems like your comment should be an answer, though? Idk, I'm also new to Meta, you're obviously not ;) EDIT: Oh, nvm, I didn't notice you'd closed it as a duplicate. Thanks!