# Disputed review audit, am I doing this right?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I just failed this [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26530017) on the first posts queue by flagging the question as Needs details or clarity, which I did for the following reasons (taken from [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)):

- Title really undescriptive
- Starts with an edit so it's hard to tell when does the question really starts
- Ultimately there is no question asked

Of course I might be wrong, in which case I would appreciate feedback about it, the thing is that I can't find here in the meta (or anywhere else) a clear procedure on how to deal with these review adutis.

From [Should I report a bad “First Post” audit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397446/should-i-report-a-bad-first-post-audit) I get that I should actually do what I'm doing right now, ask about it with the `disputed-review-audits` tag.

From [Reporting bad review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255831/reporting-bad-review-audit) I get that I should follow the link and flag the question either way, which as the question actually got answered and accepted long ago I don't feel it would make any difference.

And also from [Add an “I don't understand” option for review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/add-an-i-dont-understand-option-for-review-audits/188790#188790)
 I get that this has been going for several years without a real solution (?).

What should I do about this particular audit? What should I do in general and could this be written somewhere visible?

Comment: So what exactly did you select ad the action that should be taken

Comment: flag post -> needs improvement -> needs details or clarity

Comment: From an outsider's point of view (someone who does not indulge or know anything about that topic), this question does seem like it needs details or clarity, but I assume people who are less foreign to it can probably understand why it should ***not*** be flagged better than me or you. I think that *test review audits* should be screened to make sure they pass no matter your skill level in the subject, weeding out things that would be confusing to non-specialists in the question, as for the `I don't understand` option, isn't that what skip is for?

Comment: Regarding the `I don't understand` option, that's my bad, I was actually trying to highlight the accepted answer to that question which proposes a contest method for audits, should have specified. I understand that often someone who knows further on the subject can manage to interpret the question needing less information, but as questions are also intended for future reference (often for not so experienced people) I think it's possitive to let newcomers know they should write clearer questions.

Comment: There are some questions and answer, that i also misinterpreted, that is the flaw of this review, system, that it doesn't take into account, the peoples fuzziness, when viewing something and making decisions. it tell, you a high upvote count is an indicator fro a good Question/answer which it clearly isn't, but somehow the system has to decide which question/answers it should use to train you the system wants you to.

Comment: The post is poorly phrased & the inappropriate answer pasted onto the beginning makes it even harder to follow. But it was simpler when it got all its votes (see the timeline & edit history) & people were able to figure out what was meant from the simpler prose & the non-prose content. Just a fluke, not a good review post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: First of all thank you all for the feedback. That last question is similar to the second one I referenced, then in the future I should go to the question and flag it outside the review queue. Should I also report here in meta?

Comment: I thought that once a post had been edited, it was no longer selectable as an audit. Or did I misunderstand something? But anyway, with the edit (now rolled back), this was a very poor audit.